# how to create a blade template in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a challenge: I can't get a blade file working as expected following the Laravel guide for such a purpose.

I know a Laravel blade file must end with the `.blade.php`.

Every time I create a blade file, I get an error as the file cannot be found, but that is not the case with a pure PHP file.

Below is my route definition to return my blade test file, `testblade.blade.php`:

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return view('testblade');
});
```

When returning a pure PHP file in my route file, `testphpalone.php`, I define my route as follow:

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return view('testphpalone');
});
```

I'm concerned because I cannot use blade helper functions such as `@yield()` and `@extends()` directly in the pure PHP file, but a blade one (which I can't get working).

What am I doing wrong and how can I make it work?

Comment: Just double check the path and the name of your blade is correct. There is nothing wrong with your route function.

Comment: Are you sure to have `testblade.blade.php` (your blade test file) in the right directory?

Comment: yes my blade template in located at resource/views folder

Comment: What is the exact error you get (when you try to access your blade file in a browser)?

Comment: The error is "The localhost page isn’t working"

Comment: Is it a Laravel error or an error from your localhost server *(either: xampp, wampp, or any other)*? Please copy and paste the exact error message here.

Comment: that is the exact error., and every time I test in my browser (Im using google chrome here) there is a pop up window saying that the CLI  was stopped working

Comment: I finally came up with creating new project, and it solve my problem though I don't know exactly what is the error.

thank you every one for helping, I learned a lot from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into consideration your route definition;

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return view('testblade');
});
```

your blade template file should be `testblade.blade.php` and located in your `resources/views` directory as in: `resources/views/testblade.blade.php` for a proper implementation.

Comment: yes my blade template in located at resource/views folder.

Comment: I finally came up with creating new project, and it solve my problem though I don't know exactly what is the error.

thank you every one for helping, I learned a lot from you.

Answer (score 1):

you only can use blade syntax in a blade file. As a best practice always name view files using `.blade.php` syntax.

find more on blade syntax [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade)

Comment: ah, thanks for your comment, but how will I solve my problem? because everytime I put .blade.php file extension, it cannot route to the browser

Comment: Where is your teatblade.blade.php located

Comment: my blade template in located at resource/views folder, by the way Im using Sublime Text editor

Comment: I finally came up with creating new project, and it solve my problem though I don't know exactly what is the error.

thank you every one for helping, I learned a lot from you.

Answer (score 1):

In config\view.php check the path of the views

```
'paths' => [
    realpath(base_path('resources/views')),
]
```

Comment: yes that syntax is there.
thank you sir for your help.

Comment: The error is "The localhost page isn’t working"

thank you for your help

Comment: I finally came up with creating new project, and it solve my problem though I don't know exactly what is the error.

thank you every one for helping, I learned a lot from you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was the server, I was using the XAMPP. How I found out is that I ran my project on an online server and it worked perfectly.

The Solution is just to run your project using the command:

```html
php artisan serve
```

then browse your project using:

```
localhost:8000
```